# Content goes over the navbar and does not shrink or move whenever I resize the browser

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure this out ever since earlier. I've managed to figure out how to keep the navbar in place, but now that I did, the content goes over it and it won't shrink whenever I would resize the browser. I'm still learning how to code so any help and feedback would be really appreciated.

I'd like for the transparent background and the text to shrink or follow along whenever I resize the browser with the navbar in place. Here are my codes.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-image: url('bg2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
  overflow: visible;
}

* html .clearfix {
  min-height: 1%;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

ul li:firstchild {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #d88d4c;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 10%;
}

#image {
  width: 100%px;
  height: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 700px;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 5% 25%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(31, 22, 25, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5%;
}

#right {
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.club {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}

.bacon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}

.pork {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}

.section {
  margin: 60px 50px;
}

.section h1 {
  font: 55px/65px Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.section p {
  font: 15px/25px Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  z-index: 500;
  float: left;
  background-color: #1f1619;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 5% 0% 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Watershed</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="watershed.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="left">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#home"><img src="logo.png"></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="section">
          <h1><a name="home">HOME</a></h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise
            non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros.
            Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
          <h1><a name="about">ABOUT US</a></h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise
            non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros.
            Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
          <h1><a name="menu">MENU</a></h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise
            non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros.
            Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>

          <div id="image"><img src="be.jpg" class="bacon" alt="bacon and eggs">

            <img src="cs.jpg" class="club" alt="club sandwich">

            <img src="hu.jpg" class="pork" alt="humba"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="section">
          <h1><a name="contact">CONTACT</a></h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise
            non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros.
            Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is this you want**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-image: url('bg2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
  overflow: visible;
}

* html .clearfix {
  min-height: 1%;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:firstchild {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #d88d4c;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 10%;
}

#image {
  width: 100%px;
  height: 50%;
}

#container {
  width: 63%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(31, 22, 25, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#right {
  width: 83%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 17%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.club {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}

.bacon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}

.pork {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
}

.section {
  margin: 60px 50px;
}

.section h1 {
  font: 55px/65px Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.section p {
  font: 15px/25px Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  z-index: 500;
  float: left;
  background-color: #1f1619;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 5% 0% 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#home"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;MENU</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="section">
        <h1><a name="home">HOME</a></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non
          velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam
          ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <h1><a name="about">ABOUT US</a></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non
          velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam
          ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <h1><a name="menu">MENU</a></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non
          velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam
          ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
        <div id="image"><img src="be.jpg" class="bacon" alt="bacon and eggs"> <img src="cs.jpg" class="club" alt="club sandwich"> <img src="hu.jpg" class="pork" alt="humba"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <h1><a name="contact">CONTACT</a></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non
          velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam
          ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteture adipscing elit. Sispendise non velit felis. Vestiblum eget orci. Preasent sit amet porta eros. Nam ullamcorper lacina mi ac laculis. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```